# ng-if not working when nested table iteration using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

when table inside table repeating dynamically in that time ng-if is not working.when am adding one row in child table in that time taking wrong parent index.am using like that but in input filed working fine but buttons are not working when ng-if condition taking wrong parent index

**eg:**

```
<div  id="parentdivId" ng-repeat="parent in listOfParentTables">

            <table >
            <thead class="evlhead ingpopuphead">
              <tr>
                <th >A</th>
                <th >B</th>               
                <th >C</th> 
              </tr>
            </thead> 

            <tbody >
             <tr  ng-repeat="child in parent.childMaster" ng-if="child.status!=2">  
             <td > 
              <select   id="a10" ng-model="child.a10">
               <option ng-repeat="list in listMaster" value={{list.ID}}>{{list.NAME}}</option>
              </select>  
              </td> 
             <td ><div class="addrembtn" ><input class="btnadd" type="button" value="+" id="addbutton10"  ng-click="addNewChildRow($parent.$index,$index)"><input class="btnrem" type="button" value="-" id="deletebutton10"  ng-click="removechildRow($parent.$index,$index)"></div></td>
            </tr>
               </tbody> 
           </table>


           <div style="float:left;"> 
            <button class="parentbtn" style="margin:37px 0px 0px 17px !important;width: 75px;" value="AddTable" id="basebutton" ng-click="addNewParenttable($index)">+ &nbsp;Gasto</button>
          </div>
          <div style="float:left;"> 
            <button class="parentbtn" style="margin: 12px 0px 0px 17px !important;width: 75px;" value="AddTable" id="basebutton" ng-click="removeParenttable($index)">- &nbsp;Eliminar</button>
          </div>

           </div>
```

Comment: show the full table with ng repeat

Comment: Refer to my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111636/index-of-object-in-array-while-using-ng-repeat-and-a-filter/37085767#37085767. It might help you

Comment: In above code when ng-if condtion removed it is working fine but I wanna put that condion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nested ng-repeat, the $index does not give the index of element in the array being iterated. Use something like,

```
ng-click="addNewChildRow(listOfParentTables.indexOf(parent),parent.childMaster.indexOf(child))"
ng-click="addNewParenttable(listOfParentTables.indexOf(parent))"
```

indexOf always returns the original index in an ng-repeat
[Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/902/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for replay.Ill try this one.

Comment: Thanks alot :) Happy to help